# Why cant this binary search find my value?

Tags: javascript, binary-search

> hi everyone, my binary search keeps returning 'not found', because it cant find the value im passing it. please let me know what im doing wrong, thanks!

```
const binary_search = (arr, value) => {
let high = arr.length -1;
let low = 0;
let mid = 0;

while (low <= high){
    mid = Math.floor = ((high + low) / 2)
    //middle value being searched
    if (arr[mid] == value){
        //return value
        return arr[mid];
    } else if (value > arr[mid]){
        // move the low up one
        low = mid + 1;
    }   else  {
        // move the high down one
        high = mid -1;
    }
}
return 'not found'
}


let array = [12, 45, 37, 37, 84, 61, 12, 266]



let sorted = array.sort (function(a,b){return a-b})
let wif = binary_search(sorted,37)
console.log(sorted)
console.log(wif)
```

Comment: try `mid = Math.floor((high + low) / 2)`

Comment: yes this worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const binary_search = (arr, value) => {
    let high = arr.length -1;
    let low = 0;
    let mid = 0;

    while (low <= high){
        mid = Math.floor = ((high + low) / 2)
        mid = Math.round(mid);

        //middle value being searched
        if (arr[mid] == value){
            //return value
            return arr[mid];
        } else if (value > arr[mid]){
            // move the low up one
            low = mid + 1;
        }   else  {
            // move the high down one
            high = mid -1;
        }
    }
    return 'not found'
    }


    let array = [12, 45, 37, 37, 84, 61, 12, 266]



    let sorted = array.sort (function(a,b){return a-b})
    let wif = binary_search(sorted,37)
    console.log(sorted)
    console.log(wif)
```

The Value in of mid = Math.floor = ((high + low) / 2) are in interger in every iteration due to which it cannot get the index. Like 7 / 2 = 3.5 and arr[3.5]. there will be no value.

Answer (score -1):

Your code says:

```
mid = Math.floor = ((high + low) / 2)
```

I dont think thats what you meant there